# How to access checkbox value from a listbox in windows phone

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, checkbox, listbox

I have 10 checkboxes in a `listbox` in windows phone. 
My `xaml` file for checkbox into `listbox` is given below:

```
<ListBox x:Name="notificationSettingsListBox" Grid.Row="1"   Margin="20,20,20,20" Background="#e79e38"  >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="#055cc3" Width="500" Height="200">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding channel_name}" Foreground="White" FontSize="31" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
                        <CheckBox  Content="Enable Notification"  Checked="pushNotiOnCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="pushNotiOnCheckBox_Unchecked"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

How can I access all  checkboxes one by one like `checkbox1.checked=true` or `checkbox2.checked=false` and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you subscribe to both Checked and Unchecked events, one thing you could do is add this in the handlers

```
var box = (sender as CheckBox);
var value = box.IsChecked;
```

Comment: I want to access the checkbox outside the event handlers . How can i do that? @Dimitris Batsougiannis

Comment: I you only need 10 checkboxes, just name them like checkbox1-2-3. and access them by their identifier